# please help me to solution $\lim_{ x\to \infty} \ (2+5x)^{1/(5x)}$

Tags: limits

**Help me to  solution**

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (2+5x)^{1/(5x)}. $$

thank you for answer

Answer (score 4):

Try "substituting" $\infty$ into $x$ and observe what happens.

We have $\infty^0$. We could be bold and say that this limit probably goes to $1$ as we have seen that when we have a real number $a\neq0$ raised to the power $0$, then $a^0=1$. But let's be careful as this number we are dealing with is $\infty^0$.

Whenever we have some limit that approaches an indeterminate form like $1^\infty$, we generally make a natural log substitution and it will become obvious why.

Let $Y=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(2+5x)^{\frac{1}{5x}}$

Then, $\ln(Y)=\ln\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(2+5x)^{\frac{1}{5x}}\right) $ but by the limit properties, we can move this natural log inside and we have 
$\ln(Y)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\ln[(2+5x)^{\frac{1}{5x}}]$.

Using the natural log property   $\quad\!\!\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$ we have that

$\ln(Y)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\ln(2+5x)}{5x}\rightarrow \dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$

If you are familiar with [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html), we now have the following limit:

$\ln(Y)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{\frac{5}{2+5x}}{5}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{2+5x}=0$

But remember that since $\ln(Y)=0$, $Y=e^0=1$ and the limit indeed goes to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$L = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (2 + 5x)^{1/(5x)}$

$\ln(L) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{ln(2 + 5x)}{5x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{(2 + 5x)} = 0$

$L = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the limit of the logarithm $l=\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left((2+5x)^{1/(5x)}\right)$:

$$
l=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln(2+5x)}{5x}
$$
Use L'Hopitals rule to show that $l=0$. Now observe that:
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} (2+5x)^{1/(5x)}=e^l=1
$$